# Remove DateTime from Highchart's x-axis

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

What I have is a Highchart plotting data points every second. 1 data point per second. Now, On the X-axis what I have is the Timedata.

What I want is that to remove the time data from the x-axis and instead of that I just want to show the no. of points count. that is being plotted.

Here is the Demo code of the data plots how it looks.

```
       numArray = [1,5,3,5,6,3,3,7,4,6,7,3,5,3,6,7,5,2,5,7,4,6,4,5,3,6,7,8,5,4,3,6,7,8,5,7,8,8,5,3,2,4,6,7,4,6,7] ;


        var json_array =numArray ;

        var i = 0;
        function next() {  

          return json_array[i++];
        }
        Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line',
        animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
        marginRight: 10,
        events: {
            load: function() {

                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                var series = this.series[0],
                    chart = this;

                setInterval(function() {
                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                        y =next();
                        console.log(y) ;
                    series.addPoint([x, y], false, true);
                }, 1000);

                setInterval(function() {
                    chart.redraw(false);
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    },

    time: {
        useUTC: false
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Live random data'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickPixelInterval: 150
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Value'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{point.x:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}<br/>{point.y:.2f}'
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        animation: false,
        name: 'Random data',
        data: (function() {
            // generate an array of random data
            var data = [],
                time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                i;

            for (i = -1000; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                data.push([
                    time + i * 10,
                    null
                ]);
            }
            return data;
        }())
    }]
});
```

Here is the Fiddle of it.

https://jsfiddle.net/abnitchauhan/jb36fLwq/

I just want to remove the timedata from the X-axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by adding custom logic to `xAxis.tickPositioner` to return appropriate tick positions and `xAxis.labels.formatter` to change the timestamps into proper point count. Check the demo and code posted below.

**Code:**

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  tickPixelInterval: 150,
  tickPositioner: function() {
    var axis = this,
      chart = axis.chart,
      ticks = [],
      divider;

    if (axis.series[0].points && axis.series[0].points.length) {
      ticks = axis.series[0].points.filter(point => point.y !== null).map(point => point.x);
    }

    divider = Math.ceil(ticks.length / 20);
    chart.customLabelDivider = divider;

    if (divider > 1) {
      ticks = ticks.filter((tick, i) => i % divider === 0);
    }

    return ticks;
  },
  labels: {
    formatter: function() {
      var chart = this.chart;

      if (this.isFirst) {
        chart.customLabelCount = 1;
      } else {
        chart.customLabelCount += chart.customLabelDivider;
      }

      return chart.customLabelCount;
    }
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w2s8Le04/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositioner
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter

Answer (score 0):

From the [Docs](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.enabled), you can disable the X-axis labels like below

```
    xAxis: {

        labels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
```

Here is the updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2xk7tnur/)

Comment: It hides the x-axis labels. that's great. but whenever I am changing the tab, and coming back to the chart tab the data gets distorted. for the time I am not accessing the chart tab.

Comment: I just want to remove the time variable. rather than just hiding it. is it possible ?.